# Better way to load image synchronously on Windows Phone?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone

I'm new to do C# Windows Phone programming.

In a nutshell, I am currently building an app that will:

Load `image A`

Load `image B`

and then Load `image C`

then use these 3 images to do some post processing.

My Image B and Image C are build as `Content` within the project.
Image A is chosen from Gallery or taken via camera, or we can simply assume that Image A is load from Isolated Storage.

I am experiencing a problem which I believe caused by asynchronous image loading.

Here's my code:

```
...
// I intend to load the 3 pictures by calling the method: LoadImage(int id) and LoadCImage();

            else if (ListBox.SelectedIndex == 0)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Selected 0");
                PhotoProcessor pp = new PhotoProcessor();
                WriteableBitmap imageA = new WriteableBitmap(AImage);
                WriteableBitmap imageB = LoadImage(0);
                WriteableBitmap imageC = LoadCImage();
                WriteableBitmap mix = pp.Mix(pp.CalcAverageColour(0), imageA, imageB, imageC);
                resultPic.Source = mix;
            }
...
```

And:

```
private WriteableBitmap LoadImage(int id)
        {
            //String uriString = "/Assets/img0.jpg";            
            //BitmapImage img = new BitmapImage(new Uri(uriString, UriKind.Relative));
            BitmapImage img = new BitmapImage();
            img.CreateOptions = BitmapCreateOptions.None;
            //img.SetSource(Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri("/Assets/facetemplate0.jpg", UriKind.Relative)).Stream);
            img.UriSource = new Uri("/Assets/img" + id + ".jpg", UriKind.Relative);

            //img.UriSource = new Uri(uriString, UriKind.Relative);
            return new WriteableBitmap(img);
        }

        private WriteableBitmap LoadCImage()
        {
            //BitmapImage img = new BitmapImage(new Uri("/Assets/imgC.jpg", UriKind.Relative));
            BitmapImage bmp = new BitmapImage();
            bmp.CreateOptions = BitmapCreateOptions.None;
            //img.SetSource(Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri("/Assets/imgC.jpg", UriKind.Relative)).Stream);
            bmp.UriSource = new Uri("/Assets/imgC.jpg", UriKind.Relative);
            return new WriteableBitmap(bmp);
        }
```

Now my question is:

When I'm trying to run this code, it will throw a Null Reference Exception, which is because of the function `mix` can't load Image A B and C (loading this images are asynchronously).

I wonder if there's a way to let me sequentially load these images then let me to pass them to the `mix` function?

What I've tried:

1. By checking [this great blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/swick/archive/2011/04/07/image-tips-for-windows-phone-7.aspx), I'm able to know that there do have some way to load the image synchronously, but as you can see throughout my code, I tried to use `SetSource(stream)` like the blogpost, but unfortunately I got the same Null Reference Exception.
2. I've also thought about the `EventHandler` method, however I don't think its a good idea in this case. If I implement `EventHandler`, would it be something like(pseudo code):

   ```
   imageA_Opened()
   {
   LoadImageB += imageB_Opened();
   }

   imageB_Opened()
   {
    LoadImageC += imageC_Opened();
   }

   imageC_Opened()
   {
   PhotoProcessor pp = new PhotoProcessor();
   pp.Mix(averageColour, A, B, C);
   }
   ```

Am I right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not *supposed* to be able to download an image sequentially.  It would certainly be easier to develop, yes, but it wouldn't be nearly as effective because you would be blocking the processor for an extended period of time, thus freezing your application.

> I've also thought about the EventHandler method, however I don't think its a good idea in this case. If I implement EventHandler, would it be something like (pseudo code):

Yep, it would follow that general pattern as you have described it.  That's the appropriate way to address this problem.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. So the idea in my pseudo code is the better way? By using 3 `EventHandler`s?

Comment: You can use Rx for systemically control various events. Or if you develop on WP8, you can use async/await feature to handle event processing in synchronous manner.

Answer (score 2):

Servy is correct in saying you shouldn't block the UI with synchronous calls.

With that being said, I had a similar requirement in a WP7 app. I used "Async CTP" to add the ability to write synchronous like functions that wait until it's done before making the next call. I had API calls that required data from earlier calls to function correctly.

I believe this was included in .NET 4.5 and works on WP8.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/vstudio/hh191443.aspx

Here is what I wrote to pull data for my app (Notice the "**async**" and "**await**" keywords):

```
public async Task<bool> GetDefaultData()
{
    try
    {
        _cancellation = new CancellationTokenSource();

        UpdateProgress(DateTime.Now + ": Download Started.\n");
        List<string> data = await App._apiConnection.DoWorkAsync(_cancellation.Token, ApiInfo.GetBaseDataUriList());
        App._apiConnection.Done(data);

        UpdateProgress(DateTime.Now + ": Countries: " + App._context.Countries.Count() + "\n");
        UpdateProgress(DateTime.Now + ": Regions: " + App._context.Regions.Count() + "\n");
        UpdateProgress(DateTime.Now + ": Income Levels: " + App._context.IncomeLevels.Count() + "\n");
        UpdateProgress(DateTime.Now + ": Indicators: " + App._context.Indicators.Count() + "\n");

        data = await App._apiConnection.DoWorkAsync(_cancellation.Token, ApiInfo.GetCountryUriList("CA"));
        App._apiConnection.Done(data);
        UpdateProgress(DateTime.Now + ": CA Population: " + App._context.PopulationDatas.Count(c => c.Country.Iso2Code == "CA") + "\n");

        data = await App._apiConnection.DoWorkAsync(_cancellation.Token, ApiInfo.GetCountryUriList("US"));
        App._apiConnection.Done(data);
        UpdateProgress(DateTime.Now + ": US Population: " + App._context.PopulationDatas.Count(c => c.Country.Iso2Code == "US") + "\n");

        data = await App._apiConnection.DoWorkAsync(_cancellation.Token, ApiInfo.GetCountryUriList("CN"));
        App._apiConnection.Done(data);
        UpdateProgress(DateTime.Now + ": CN Population: " + App._context.PopulationDatas.Count(c => c.Country.Iso2Code == "CN") + "\n");

        return true;
    }
    catch (OperationCanceledException)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Operation Cancelled");
        return false;



    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("getDefaultData Exception: " + ex.Message);

        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: cheers mate, i'm now working for a WP7.5 project whose Async CTP has bugs that won't let me to install it. I'll try Async CTP later when the project is moved to WP8. Thanks.

Comment: I had that problem. I uninstalled all hotfixes then reinstalled VS2010, the Service Pack THEN the Async CTP. then I reapplied all the hotfixes. Then it worked like a champ for me. Hope this helps!

Comment: Yeah, thanks for the advice. I did some search about this issue and found a similar solution to you. But I'm now under Windows 8 :-[

Comment: My issue was on Windows 8. I run both VS2010 and 2012 at the same time. I can't drop 2010 yet so I had to fix the issue. I know you can fix your Async CTP install issue if you need to. :)